# Internet proxy not working until IE is refreshed

Tags: google-chrome, internet, proxy, internet-explorer

My work PC was recently upgraded to Windows 7, and now I'm noticing strange behaviour: Chrome would frequently, usually within the hour or so, fail to access the web. I get the error "The webpage is not available" Chrome page. To fix it, I have to open IE, go to my corporate home page, and then navigate to an external web site - then Chrome will happily access the web again (until it happens again).

This issue is not related to Chrome - my Firefox using team mates have exactly the same problem. It seems that my corporate internet proxy settings are cached somehow, and after the cache expires, I need to access the web again via IE in order to restore the settings.

When I open my Internet Connection settings, I have the following: "Automatically detect settings" is disabled, and "Use automatic configuration script" is enabled and points to some .js file. The manual proxy configuration text controls are empty and greyed out (I do not have permission to change them) .

My corporate help desk are no help as they don't support non-IE browsers, and this problem does not seem to manifest with IE. Also, Googling the issue returns a lot of noise since I have no clear understanding of the problem in the first place.

My question has two legs, really:

1. What is causing this behaviour? If I have an explanation of what the cause is, I could perhaps get someone in my corporate help desk team to look at it.
2. Is there something I can do on my work PC to fix or alleviate the problem? I have admin rights on my machine so I can update the registry, but my work PC is generally quite locked down (I can't change my internet access settings, for example, to use another proxy). I am a Java coder with a fair bit of C# experience, so solutions requiring a bit of coding is also welcome.

(If this question is on the wrong forum then please let me know too).

Update on this issue (in case anyone cares): My corporate help desk have identified that I needed to be added to a special Windows group ("Windows 7 migration users" or something similar). After this was done, the issue was fixed. I have absolutely no idea why this happened or why this fixed it, but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you configure your browser proxy settings into the browser it self (manually or GPO distributed) or those settings are distributed using DHCP wpad?

You can usually see this in your browser, you have an option that says "Auto detect proxy settings for this network" if your are getting these settings by DHCP WPAD or or "Manual proxy configuration" with all your proxy server information inserted if your using manual proxy settings.

You can see this in the browsers:
Internet Explorer/Google Chrome: Press ALT+X > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings
Firefox: Options > Advanced > Network Tab > Under Connections press Settings

My Advice is if your using wpad insert manually the proxy settings and give it a spin, if you have it manually inserted contact your network administrator, since it happens to more than 1 computer it might be something else there (proxy server issues, firewalling, etc ..).

Comment: "Automatically detect settings" is disabled, and "Use automatic configuration script" is enabled and points to some .js file. I do not have permission to change the proxy server settings (it's greyed out).

Comment: That means your using something like wpad. Can you install extensions in chrome? if so try to use falcon proxy and add your settings there to test out you are unable to do so try to talk with the computer/network administrators.